# How to edit line in text file via powershell script

Tags: powershell

I'm new in powershell world and of courser I'm stuck.
I'm trying to iterate through text file and to find some lines and to edit it.
Cannot use simple replace flag because I have some other logic involved.

So my approach is like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $JsonsFolderPath  -File -Recurse -Filter *.json | ForEach-Object {}
```

With this line I iterate through all json's in `$JsonsFolderPath`  folder.

Now, hot to iterate thorugh all line of a file and do some custom logic?

I've tried something like this: (this goes inside upper foreach)

```
$content = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName |
    ForEach-Object {
        if(//something)
        {
            return ModifyFunction($_)
        }
        else
        {
            return $_ // do not modify
        }
    } | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
```

How to approach this?

Comment: Better not try to modify json files like this. Instead, use `ConvertFrom-Json` to parse the file contents as **objects**. Modify the objects you need, then use `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99` and save as new json file with `Set-Content`

Answer (score 0):

you can loop over the lines in powershell

```
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(<file_path>)) {
    $line.Replace('<original_string>', '<new_string>')
}
```

you can also add conditions or a counter to only edit specific line or at a specific line number. For the specific line number, just declare a counter variable before the for-loop and a target line number. Increment the counter by 1 in the for loop and check, whether $counter -eq $targetLineNumber before you replace the contents in that line.

If you know the exact string, you want to replace, then i refer you to this link:

https://shellgeek.com/powershell-replace-line-in-file/

Cheers.

Comment: Okay, but how to write that edited line to file? I have function which edits line. How to apply that new line to current line?

Comment: With Set-Content, every time, you update a line. :) As i said, reference in the link.

Comment: My problem is where to place that Set-Content? Because I cannot pipe on foreach

Comment: You do not have to pipe that. Just add a new line.

Comment: Also, consider using -replace instead of Replace(). -replace lets you use regex directly.